# Como puedo hace una navegación por una pagina web, si tengo el botton fuera del contexto? Flutter web

Tags: web, flutter, dart, responsive, headers

tengo un gran problemas, he creado una clase llamada HeaderItem esta clase le he pasado los parámetros title, ontap y isbutton. Tengo como objetivo crear un header en un pagina we.

```
class HeaderItem {
  final String title;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final bool isButton;

  HeaderItem({
    required this.title,
    required this.onTap,
    this.isButton = false,
  });
}
```

Hice el llamado a esta clase y la he asignado tipo lista.

```
List<HeaderItem> headerItems = [
  HeaderItem(
    title: "HOME",
    onTap: () {},
  ),
  HeaderItem(title: "MY INTRO", onTap: () {}),
  HeaderItem(title: "SERVICES", onTap: () {}),
  HeaderItem(title: "PORTFOLIO", onTap: () {}),
  HeaderItem(title: "TESTIMONIALS", onTap: () {}),
  HeaderItem(title: "BLOGS", onTap: () {}),
  HeaderItem(
    title: "HIRE ME",
    onTap: () {},
    isButton: true,
  ),
];
```

Sin embargo, como pueden ver esta clase esta fuera del statelessWitget, como les comentaba el objetivo es hacer un header, con esta lista agrego todos los items, pero no se como puedo hacer funcionar el obtap si esta fuera del contexto, no puedo navegar a donde necesito realmente.

```
class HeaderRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const HeaderRow({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveVisibility(
      visible: false,
      visibleWhen: const [
        Condition.largerThan(name: MOBILE),
      ],
      child: Row(
        children: headerItems
            .map(
              (item) => item.isButton
                  ? MouseRegion(
                      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: kDangerColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 5.0),
                        child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: item.onTap,
                          child: Text(
                            item.title,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 13.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : MouseRegion(
                      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30.0),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: item.onTap,
                          child: Text(
                            item.title,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 13.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Estoy atento a sus opiniones. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes 2 formas de hacerlo.

1- Tu clase `HeaderItem` podría recibir el context, en lugar de un `VoidCallback` podrías usar un `ValueChanged<BuildContext>`.

```dart
final ValueChanged<BuildContext> onTap;


HeaderItem(
    title: "HOME",
    onTap: (context) {
       Navigator.of(context).push...
    },
  ),

y lo llamarías así: 

onTap: () =>  item.onTap(context),
```

No te recomiendo esa opción, ya que estarías repitiendo mucho código en todos los items.

2- En el `HeaderRow` en lugar de usar el `onTap` de tus items, puedes directamente hacer el llamado al Navigator, así.

```dart
 TextButton(
          onPressed: (){
              // puedes usar tu Item aquí y pasarlo como parámetro.
              // Si `MyAppScreen` requiere parámetro, le puedes pasar el `item` que ya tienes.
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyAppScreen()));
          },
          child: Text(
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por ayudarme! Soy algo nuevo en esto. Realice la opción 1 y me ha quedado así...

`List<HeaderItem> headerItems = [
  HeaderItem(
    title: "HOME",
    onTap: (context) {
      Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyAppScreen()));
    },
  ),`

Pero no sé como llamarla en el botton 

`child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              
                              
                            },`


También hice el segundo pero, no se como usar los items ahi en el boton

Comment: ya actualicé mi respuesta, de todas maneras te recomiendo que leas esto https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: Muchas gracias diego! En serio me ha servido muchísimo, saludos...